# Python 2 modules in same folder, one can be imported, the other shows ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-import

project folder structure like this:

```
- Project
|- main_code.py
|- func_1
   |- models
      |- __init__.py
      |- a.py
      |- b.py
```

The `__init__.py` has these code inside:

```
from a import XXX
from b import YYY
```

When I tried to call functions in `a.py` and `b.py` from `main_code.py`, I wrote this in `main_code.py`:

```
from func_1.models.a import XXX
from func_1.models.b import YYY
```

I have no problem with import XXX from module a, but for YYY I got the error message: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'b'

Nothing related to the sequence. I tried with different sequence, still have problem finding the module `b`. For module `a` everything seems ok.

I have no idea why the functions with same coding structure and path, one can be called and the other can not.

Comment: I assume `__init__.py`, `a.py`, and `b.py` are all supposed to be inside `models`.  That's not what your diagram shows.

Comment: @TimRoberts You are right, my mistake, Just modified the question part.. These 3 files are all inside `models` folder.

Comment: Something is not as you say.   I just tried this exact configuration and it worked fine.

Comment: @TimRoberts That's why I feel so weird. I created new folder like the name show in the question, it works. And I change the name for my current program files, not work, same issue, no matter what kind of name I gave to module `b`, same error. But module `a` works.

Comment: Are you literally using `a` and `b` or are those shrouded names?  Even if you've checked three times for spelling errors, check again.

Comment: @TimRoberts I solved the problem. I change the  `__init__.py`, instead of `from a import XXX` I change to `from .a import XXX`. Now `a` and `b` both work. But I don't understand cause usually when you want to call a function under the same folder, you don't need to add '.' before it.

Comment: Now that you have that in `__init__`, your main code can just day `from func_l.models import XXX, YYY`.

Comment: The key is not really "in the same folder".  They key is "in the Python path".  When you run a script from the command line, that folder goes in the path.  But when you import `models`, for example, that doesn't go in the path, so the lower modules can't find each other.

Comment: @TimRoberts I see. I changed to the way of `from func_1.models import XXX,YYY`. And thanks for the explanation of the path concept.